# Java package , cannot find symbol

Tags: java, package

I am trying to follow this basic guide:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm
When I compile the file MammalInt.java I have an error:

```
MammalInt.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public class MammalInt implements Animal{
                              ^
symbol: class Animal
1 error
```

Both the files Animal.java and MammalInt.java are in the same directory. I have already compiled Animal.java.
Please help me!

Comment: Where is your Animal interface?

Comment: And how are you trying to compile?

Comment: Do they both declare the same package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should:

- Make sure the filenames are correct (`Animal.java` and `MammalInt.java` - the same as the class names with `.java` file extension)
- Make sure they are both in a directory called `animals` (same as the package name)
- Make sure they both have `package animals;` at the top of the files
- Compile tham at the same time with the command `javac Animal.java MammalInt.java`

That works.

Comment: This works!!Thank you to everybody!!! :-) I had to compile both at the same time with javac Animal.java MammalInt.java

Comment: I am new to Java...curious why they must be compiled at the same time. I come from a C background where a header file is good enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add on top of both files this:

```
package animals;
```

it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Classes have two access modifier: public and default.If you are making a class default that will be access-able from all other packages but if you are not specifying any access modifier i.e if you are giving default modifier that means that class will be access-able from the package where this class belong to.